# How to setup a controller's method using moq

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, moq

I have an action method in my controller as below

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     var supplier = GetSupplierForUser();
     var model = SupplierService.GetOutstandingItems(supplier);          
     return View(model);
}
```

I've setup the supplier service method as

```
var supplierService = new Mock<ISupplierService>();
var supplier = new Supplier { Name = "Some Name",Id = 100};

supplierService.Setup(s => s.GetOutstandingItems(supplier))
                            .Returns(outstandingSupplierItemInfo.Object);
```

I don't know how can we setup the method `Supplier GetSupplierForUser()` which is present in the base controller to return a Supplier object. From the moq setup above a null supplier is always passed to  `SupplierService.GetOutstandingItems(supplier)`

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: What is `outstandingSupplierItemInfo.Object`? And what is the model that `GetOutstandingItems()` returns?

Comment: Does `Supplier GetSupplierForUser()` method use `SupplierService` to get supplier for user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need:

```
supplierService.Setup(s => s.GetOutstandingItems(It.IsAny<Supplier>()))
    .Returns(outstandingSupplierItemInfo.Object);
```

The `It.IsAny<>` stuff will make your `Setup` match any incoming object (argument).

Since you use a loose mock, if no `Setup` matches the arguemnts in question, Moq will just return `null`. Consider using `MockBehavior.Strict` to have an exception instead.

If you do not use `It.IsAny<>`, Moq will have to try to see if the supplier that is passed to Moq, "is equal to" the `supplier` you used when you made the `Setup`. Here it can become important what `.Equals(...)` semantics your type (`class` or `struct`) `Supplier` has.

If you do not have the relevant `Equals` semantics, but still want to restrict the `Setup` to a particular situation, try this instead:

```
supplierService
    .Setup(s => s.GetOutstandingItems(It.Is((Supplier s) => s.Name == "Some Name" && s.Id == 100)))
    .Returns(outstandingSupplierItemInfo.Object);
```